# Refresh specific component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using functional component in React and i'm trying to reload the component after button is clicked.

```
  import { useCallback, useState } from 'react';

  const ProfileLayout = () => {
  const [reload, setReload] = useState(false);

  const onButtonClick = useCallback(() => {
  setReload(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    {reload && (
        <ProfileDetails />
    )}
    <Button onClick={onButtonClick} />
  );

  };
export default ProfileLayout;
```

I'm not able to see again the component after page loaded.
Note: I don't want to use `window.location.reload();`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We should be able to copy/paste the code and run it ourselves without any errors.

Comment: I have updated  my code.

Comment: I still can't reproduce the behavior you are asking about because `ProfileDetails` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: I don't want to use `window.location.reload();`

That is good because that is not the correct way to do this in React. Forcing the browser to reload will lose all of your component or global state.

The correct way to force a component to render is to call `this.setState()` or call `this.forceUpdate()`.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by reloading the component? You want to re-render it or you want to make the component fetch the data again? Like "refresh"?

Anyways the way your component is coded the `<ProfileDetails />` component will not show up on the first render since you are doing `reload && <ProfileDetails />`, but `reload` is initially false. When you click the button then ProfileDetails will appear, but another click on the button won't have any effect since `reload` is already set to `true`.

If you want to refresh the data the component uses, then you need to implement a callback that triggers the data fetching.

### Edit after clarification by author

```js
const ProfileContainer = (props) => {
  
  // initialProfile is the profile data that you need for your component. If it came from another component, then you can set it when the state is first initialized.

  const [ profile, setProfile ] = useState(props.initialProfile);

  const loadProfile = useCallback( async () => {
    // fetch data from server
    const p = await fetch('yourapi.com/profile'); // example
    setProfile(p);
  }

  return (<><ProfileDetails profile={profile} /> <button onClick={loadProfile} /></>)

}
```

### Alternate approach to load the data within the component

```js
const ProfileContainer = (props) => {
 
  const [ profile, setProfile ] = useState(null);

  const loadProfile = useCallback( async () => {
    // fetch data from server
    const p = await fetch('yourapi.com/profile'); // example
    setProfile(p);
  }

  useEffect(() => loadProfile(), []); // Empty dependency so the effect only runs once when component loads.
  

  return (<>
            { /* needed since profile is initially null */ 
              profile && <ProfileDetails profile={profile} /> 
            } 

             <button onClick={loadProfile} />
           </>);
};
```

Comment: Ok but what is the reason for re-rendering? Is it to refresh the data?

I'm asking so I can give you the best solution.

Comment: Yes, this is to refresh the data. Or to refresh whole page is good solution too

Comment: No, refreshing the whole page is not a good solution.

Then what you have to do is implement a callback that fetches the data, then trigger it on button click.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused with `initialProfile` and the prop `profile` inside ProfileDetails.

Answer (score 0):

```
const ProfileLayout = () => {
  const [reload, setReload] = useState(0);

  const onButtonClick = useCallback(() => {
    setReload(p => p+1);
  }, []);

  return (
    {Boolean(reload) && (
        <ProfileDetails />
    )}
  );

  };
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to force the refresh, then better use a number than a boolean.

```
const ProfileLayout = () => {
  const [reload, setReload] = useState(0);

  const onButtonClick = useCallback(() => {
    setReload(p => p+1);
  }, []);

  return (
    {Boolean(reload) && (
        <ProfileDetails />
    )}
  );

  };
```